# New 14.04.4 LTS Install unable to connect to networks ethernet or wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, ethernet

I'm a new Linux user. Strong Windows user but not a programmer. I installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 on my old Dell Inspiron 1501. I am not able to connect to my Home network via Ethernet or wifi. I'm not able to toggle wifi on.

```
sudo lspci
```

Result is:

```
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 801.11b/g WLAN (rev01)
Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev02)
```

Do I just need the firmware-b43-installer? If so how can I get it on a USB drive and install from there?

EDIT:
Installed `b43-fwcutter_018-2_amd64.deb` then `firmware-b43-installer_015-9_all.deb` but received and error that it could not access `broadcom-wl-5.10.56.27.3_mipsel.tar.bz2` from the mirror.

I have `broadcom-wl-5.10.56.27.3_mipsel.tar.bz2` on my USB drive but don't know how to get the installer to use it.

EDIT:

```
travatron4000@Linux-Lappy:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480/RS482/RS485 Host Bridge (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Bridge [int gfx]
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 2
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 3
00:12.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS482M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200]
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
08:01.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 19)
08:01.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C843 MMC Host Controller (rev 01)
```

Also tried this per [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215126&highlight=Ethernet+controller%3A+Broadcom+Corporation+BCM4401-B0+100Base-TX+%28rev02%29](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215126&highlight=Ethernet%20controller%3A%20Broadcom%20Corporation%20BCM4401-B0%20100Base-TX%20%28rev02%29)

```
travatron4000@Linux-Lappy:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
Selecting previously unselected package linux-firmware-nonfree.
(Reading database ... 167205 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-firmware-nonfree_1.11_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware-nonfree (1.11) ...
Setting up linux-firmware-nonfree (1.11) ...
travatron4000@Linux-Lappy:~/Desktop$ sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Then it did nothing

EDIT 3-4-16 @Pilot6:

```
travatron4000@Linux-Lappy:~$ lspci -knn | grep net -A2
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:01f5]
08:01.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter [1180:0822] (rev 19)
travatron4000@Linux-Lappy:~$
```

EDIT:

Was able to get Ethernet working with solution found here:
[Ethernet Network card BCM4401-B0 no longer recognised?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629981/ethernet-network-card-bcm4401-b0-no-longer-recognised)

EDIT:

Wifi resolved with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree

sudo modprobe b43

dmesg |grep -e b43 -e bcma
```

[Enable wifi firmware on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139150/enable-wifi-firmware-on-ubuntu-12-04/229626#229626)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.